# How to set Emoji popup position in Win32

Tags: winapi, emoji

Windows 10 has added Emoji dialog by hotkey Windows+dot. Since 2017. How can my app set position of that dialog, to show it near app's caret? C++ example is welcome.

My app uses custom-drawn control, with self made caret (written in Delphi).

[image: Examlpe of popup]

Comment: This feature didn't work on my computer, but then I tried it in OneNote and it worked, now it works with all applications and any edit control. Did I make a mistake or is there some activation going on?

Answer (score 3):

Your window's event callback function needs to handle the `WM_IME_REQUEST` message, where the `wParam` can be `IMR_QUERYCHARPOSITION`:

[WM_IME_REQUEST documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/wm-ime-request)

[IMR_QUERYCHARPOSITION documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/imr-querycharposition)

> **lParam**
>
> Pointer to an IMECHARPOSITION structure that contains the position of
> the character in the composition window.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> *Returns a nonzero value* if the application fills the
> IMECHARPOSITION structure. Otherwise, the command returns 0.

[IMECHARPOSITION documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imm/ns-imm-imecharposition)

Here is an example:

```
switch (message)
{
     // ...

     case WM_IME_REQUEST:
     {
        switch (wParam)
        {
            case IMR_QUERYCHARPOSITION:
            {
                IMECHARPOSITION * charPos = (IMECHARPOSITION *)lParam;
                charPos->dwSize = sizeof(IMECHARPOSITION);
                charPos->pt.x = ;             // SET YOUR VALUES HERE
                charPos->pt.y = ;             //  ...
                charPos->cLineHeight = ;      //  ...
                charPos->rcDocument.left = ;  //  ...
                charPos->rcDocument.top = ;   //  ...
                charPos->rcDocument.right = ; //  ...
                charPos->rcDocument.bottom = ;//  ...

                result = true;       // Return true, as required by the docs!
            } break;
        }
     } break;

     // ...
 }

 return result;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can set the focus to the Edit control and call [keybd_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event) or [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput)

For example with an Edit control *hEdit1* and **keybd_event** :

```
SetFocus(hEdit1);
keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
WORD nVkCode = LOBYTE(VkKeyScanEx('.', GetKeyboardLayout(0)));
keybd_event(nVkCode, MapVirtualKey(nVkCode, 0), 0, 0);
keybd_event(nVkCode, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Comment: It won't work. My app uses custom-drawn control, with self made caret (written in Delphi).

Comment: Can't you set the keyboard focus to your window ?